# Eliminating observations between two tables based on a formula

Tags: algorithm, loops, for-loop, foreach, stata

I have two tables:

The first table has name, date, time and intraday price variables. It means there is an intraday price for each name in a specific date and time.
The second table has name, date and daily price and the daily price is intraday price aggregation for each name and date.
I try to write a program which performs the procedure below:

It can find same observations by name and date in two tables and then:

If first and last intraday price is out of 0.962 and 1.0398 times of daily price in last day; then delete all data related to that specific name and date in table 1.

The statement is:

IF first AND last (intraday price for specific name & date) NOT IN [0.962*(daily price of yesterday), 1.0398*(daily price of yesterday)] THEN DELETE.

For instance, consider two tables which are below:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str4 name long date str8 time double intraday_price
"A" 17659 "11:32:41"    3
"A" 17659 "12:32:41"    2
"A" 17659 "13:32:41"    1
"A" 17660 "11:32:41" 3.95
"A" 17660 "12:32:41"    3
"A" 17660 "13:32:41"    6
"A" 17660 "14:32:41" 4.01
"B" 17659 "11:32:41"  3.1
"B" 17659 "12:32:41"    1
"B" 17659 "13:32:41"    4
"B" 17659 "14:32:41"  2.9
"B" 17660 "11:32:41"    6
"B" 17660 "12:32:41"    1
"B" 17661 "11:32:41"    5
"B" 17661 "12:32:41"    7
"C" 17659 "11:32:41"    3
"C" 17659 "12:32:41"    2
"C" 17660 "11:32:41"  6.1
"C" 17660 "12:32:41"    3
"C" 17660 "13:32:41"    2
"C" 17661 "11:32:41"    8
"C" 17661 "12:32:41"    2
"C" 17661 "13:32:41"    3
"C" 17661 "14:32:41"    2
end
format %d date
```

And the table 2 is:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str4 name long date double daily_price
"A" 17657 3
"B" 17657 6
"C" 17657 5
"A" 17658 5
"A" 17659 4
"B" 17658 3
"B" 17659 4
"B" 17660 3
"C" 17658 7
"C" 17659 6
"C" 17660 5
end
format %d date
```

Please consider that the daily price of yesterday should be used in formula.

So the result is:

```
+------+----------+----------+----------------+
| name |   date   |   time   | intraday price |
+------+----------+----------+----------------+
| B    | 7-May-08 | 11:32:41 |            3.1 |
| B    | 7-May-08 | 12:32:41 |              1 |
| B    | 7-May-08 | 13:32:41 |              4 |
| B    | 7-May-08 | 14:32:41 |            2.9 |
| A    | 8-May-08 | 11:32:41 |           3.95 |
| A    | 8-May-08 | 12:32:41 |              3 |
| A    | 8-May-08 | 13:32:41 |              6 |
| A    | 8-May-08 | 14:32:41 |           4.01 |
| C    | 8-May-08 | 11:32:41 |            6.1 |
| C    | 8-May-08 | 12:32:41 |              3 |
| C    | 8-May-08 | 13:32:41 |              2 |
+------+----------+----------+----------------+
```

Would you please tell me how I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't so clear that I know for sure if this is what you want, and you also have a lot of missing data (there are name-dates in table 2 that do not match with name-dates in table 1), so let me know if this is getting at what you want.

Essentially, we create both tables as temporary files. For table 2, we first create a value for the day *after* the last day in your data, since we want a "last day price" variable. Then we create the "last day price" variable (we could technically use time series operators to do this later, but this is a bit simpler). Then we merge table 2 onto table 1. I drop any observations with no intraday prices, since I am *assuming* these would be irrelevant to you, and then use bysort to create an indicator for whether you should drop. I commented out the part where we actually drop, so you can eye-ball your data first to make sure this gets at what you actually want.

First, input your data:

```
    clear
    tempfile table1 table2

//  Input data
    input str4 name long date str8 time double intraday_price
    "A" 17659 "11:32:41"    3
    "A" 17659 "12:32:41"    2
    "A" 17659 "13:32:41"    1
    "A" 17660 "11:32:41" 3.95
    "A" 17660 "12:32:41"    3
    "A" 17660 "13:32:41"    6
    "A" 17660 "14:32:41" 4.01
    "B" 17659 "11:32:41"  3.1
    "B" 17659 "12:32:41"    1
    "B" 17659 "13:32:41"    4
    "B" 17659 "14:32:41"  2.9
    "B" 17660 "11:32:41"    6
    "B" 17660 "12:32:41"    1
    "B" 17661 "11:32:41"    5
    "B" 17661 "12:32:41"    7
    "C" 17659 "11:32:41"    3
    "C" 17659 "12:32:41"    2
    "C" 17660 "11:32:41"  6.1
    "C" 17660 "12:32:41"    3
    "C" 17660 "13:32:41"    2
    "C" 17661 "11:32:41"    8
    "C" 17661 "12:32:41"    2
    "C" 17661 "13:32:41"    3
    "C" 17661 "14:32:41"    2
    end
    format %d date

    save `table1'

    clear
    input str4 name long date double daily_price
    "A" 17657 3
    "B" 17657 6
    "C" 17657 5
    "A" 17658 5
    "A" 17659 4
    "B" 17658 3
    "B" 17659 4
    "B" 17660 3
    "C" 17658 7
    "C" 17659 6
    "C" 17660 5
    end
    format %d date
```

Now, make your changes:

```
//  Create a new observation to create a "lastday_price" for the day AFTER the last day in the data
    levelsof name, local(names)
    foreach name of local names {
        set obs  `=_N+1'
        replace name = "`name'" if missing(name)
    }
    sort name date

//  Generate lastday_price
    bysort name (date): gen lastday_price = daily_price[_n-1]
    bysort name (date): replace date = date[_n-1] + 1 if missing(date)
    save `table2'

//  Merge table 2 onto table 1 by name and date
    use `table1', clear
    merge m:1 name date using `table2'
        drop if _merge == 2     // Only daily prices, no intra_day price

//  Generate indicator for whether or not to drop
    bysort name date (time): gen drop = 1 if    ///
        !inrange(intraday_price[1],0.962*lastday_price,1.0398*lastday_price) &  ///
        !inrange(intraday_price[_N],0.962*lastday_price,1.0398*lastday_price) & ///
        !missing(lastday_price)

*drop if drop == 1
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, but I have a problem. The `more` command always shows in display windows. I use the `more off` command, however, the problem still exists.

Comment: I just use `set more off` at the first of do-file. How can I use this command permanently?

Comment: I used `set more off, permanently`, but it didn't work! does it work in do-file?

Comment: Weird. Not sure about that one. Yes, it will work in the .do file, so hopefully that works!